# custom authorization in asp.net core mvc

Tags: c#, authentication, authorization, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

In asp.net core mvc project , I want to crate new user roles and give permission to each role for controller actions .
Let say , I have a `SchoolController` , inside this , I have three methods ,

- CreateSchool
- UpdateSchool
- DeleteSchool

And Let's say I have `Admin` and `Staff` roles. I want to give access all methods to `Admin` and give `UpdateSchool` to `Staff` .
Meaning is, Admin can Create,Update,Delete School . And Staff can only UpdateSchool .
I will save this roles permission inside database like

```
Role
----------------------------------------
RoleId  Name
1       Admin
2       Staff


Module
----------------------------------------
ModuleId   Name
1          SchoolController/CreateSchool
2          SchoolController/UpdateSchool
3          SchoolController/DeleteSchool

RoleModules (middle table for relation of roles and module )
----------------------------------------
RoleId      ModuleId
1           1
1           2
1           3
2           2
```

Ok , let say we have 3 persons here , Person_1, Person_2 and Person_3 .
And they have different roles like

```
Person_1 ( Admin )
Person_2 ( Staff )
Person_3 ( Staff )
```

When users access to `CreateSchool` Controller's action , I want to check if current user has access to this action or not .

```
[Authorize]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateSchool(SchoolViewModel model)
{
     //code to create school
}
```

For this , should I need to use `IAuthorizationHandler`'s `HandleRequirementAsync` ?
Where should I retrieve from database and check for user's request ?
Is there any reference that meet with my requirement ??

**Note** : Roles and Modules will dynamically create in run-time .

**Update** : Should I use `ActionFilter` ?  ( [reference](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/working-with-filters-in-asp-net-core-mvc/) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do this by using requirement and handler.

Create requirement class:

```
public class HasRoleRequirement: IAuthorizationRequirement { }
```

Then implement a handler:

```
public class RoleRequirementHandler : AuthorizationHandler<HasRoleRequirement>
{
    protected IHttpContextAccessor m_httpContextAccessor;

    public RequirementHandlerBase(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        m_httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, HasRoleRequirement requirement)
    {
        var requestPath = m_httpContextAccessor.Request.Path;
        var module = GetModule(path); // Get your module from DB
        var requiredRoles = GetRequiredRoles(module.ModuleId); // Get the required roles for the module/path
        bool isAuthorized = IsInAnyRole(m_httpContext.User, requiredRoles); // Check whether the user has any of the required roles
        if (isAuthorized)
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }
        else
        {
            context.Fail();
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Register the policy in the `ConfigureServices` method in Startup.cs:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options => 
{
    options.AddPolicy("HasRole", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new HasRoleRequirement()));
}
services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, RoleRequirementHandler>();
```

Use the authorization by decoration your method `[Authorize(Policy = "IsInRole")]`

For reusability and cleaner code, you may declare the policy name strings as constants in a static class.

See [docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52658355/custom-authorization-in-asp-net-core-mvc).

You will have to implement the methods `GetModule`. `GetRequiredRoles` and `IsInAnyRole` yourself.

Comment: it's nice using `HandleAsync` method here , but as I mentioned in question , (Admin and Staff ) roles are just for sample and those will be dynamically created in run-time . And other roles too . So , I cannot use the attribute `[Authorize(Policy = "IsAdmin")]` . any suggestion ?

Comment: You can inject `IHttpContextAccessor` into your requirement handler and use it to get the current request. Then, map the action to your roles and check if the user has the roles required. Use only one requirement, `HasRoleRequirement`, maybe.